# Session serializing in a JSF Single Page Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsf, single-page-application

I have a Single Page Application (SPA) where the MVC is managed with Java beans of different scopes, and I want to serialize the session in such a way that, through a load balancer, if one server goes down, the app can continue functioning through another server. But my concern is that I have several nested windows, and I believe that when switching servers, as the JVM addresses of the beans may be different, it might not work. Am I mistaken?